# angularJS post form data to nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I´m trying to POST data from angularJS to a nodeJS app but the body request is always empty.

**Angular (v1.6.3)**

```
vm.submitForm = function() {
    vm.formData = {name: 'test'}
    var data = $httpParamSerializer(vm.formData);
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        $http.post('/submit', data, config)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, 
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );

    }
```

**Node** *app.js*

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

**Node** *route.js*

```
router.post('/submit', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.body);
})
```

I did some research and looks like all I need is

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

but is still not working for me. thank you!

Comment: whats error are you getting?

Comment: absolutely nothing.  the req.body is {}

Comment: please watch the request in the network tab from dev console

Comment: No errors at all. but the node app is not getting anything in the body. I tried with Postman and it works. It looks like the issue is on the angular app. serverr response: POST /submit 200 4.067 ms - 2

Comment: what is  `$httpParamSerializer(vm.formData);` returning?

Comment: $httpParamSerializer(vm.formData) is returning: name=test in the browser console

Comment: Why are you sending your data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. Any specific reason?

Comment: But why do you need **$httpParamSerializer** ? in your router you are specifying **json**. You just need to do something like: `$http.post( "URL", JsonObject )`

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in your Angular Code:

`vm.submitForm = function() {
    var data = {
       "key1" : "value"
    };
    $http.post('/submit', data)
        .then(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
}`

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"} but is empty. also nodejs responds with an empty body. thank you

Comment: I think , there is some problem on server side , refer this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application) once.